# conversion factor for units in boost.units

Tags: c++, boost, boost-units

I just started using boost-units, and I am trying to understand what code I should write to get the conversion factor between units. Following the [Runtime Units Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_units/Examples.html#boost_units.Examples.RuntimeUnits), I managed to get what I need for base_units.

As an example, for length I can easily get the conversion factor from inch to meter as follows:

```
conversion_factor(imperial::inch_base_unit::unit_type(), si::meter_base_unit::unit_type())
```

This eventually allows me to define as many scaled units as I want, and get all the needed conversion factors.

In the case of velocity, for example, which is declared as 'meter_per_second' unit in the relevant header, I cant figure out how to retrieve the conversion factor to convert it to kmh, or mph. I guess I need to define my own mph unit, which leads to the need to define (or retrieve) the definition of miles and hours, and putting them all together.

How am I supposed achieve the desired result?

Comment: I'm not so sure about that linked sample. It seems to return wrong things: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/615e8be190e18463

Comment: Oh aha. That sample is not doing what you'd think it does: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt((1+foot)+%5E+2+%2B+(2m)%5E2)

Comment: @sehe the linked example is relevant only for the use of the **conversion_factor** function, which seems to return what I need. I have compiled nor run the code actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a relevant example in the Boost-users mailing list archive ([here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/boost-list/mph%7Csort:relevance/boost-list/AUw58m5XzYs/PnCxrDueClgJ))

```
#include <boost/units/base_units/us/mile.hpp>
#include <boost/units/base_units/metric/hour.hpp>

typedef boost::units::us::mile_base_unit::unit_type mile_unit;
typedef boost::units::metric::hour_base_unit::unit_type hour_unit;

typedef boost::units::divide_typeof_helper<mile_unit, hour_unit>::type miles_per_hour;
```

Once the unit is correctly declared, the **conversion_factor** function can be called to get what I need.

Comment: Using C++11 you can write it as [`using miles_per_hour = decltype(mile_unit{}/hour_unit{});` -- see live demo/proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55b960720b737c48)

Comment: @sehe thanks for the suggestion, I will investigate if I can do it, since the source code needs to be compiled with different compilers, and at the moment it is unclear to me which C++ standards we can take advantage of (at the moment we stick to C++98 -.-')